# Why is my computer not turning on?

Tags: boot, motherboard, hardware-failure, physical-damage

This has been going on for eleven months now. It's starting to get really old. I don't want to get a new computer because this one used to work perfectly until it was *destroyed* by UPS. Basically, this computer has moved with me from London, to Pittsburgh, to San Francisco, to LA, to Montreal, to Paris, and now back to San Francisco. There has never been a (big) problem. But this time, it arrived in San Francisco completely wrecked. I was very stressed, it was three weeks late, and I did not complain to UPS. I should have. This was September of last year.

In the meantime, I have:

- Replaced the case
- Replaced the motherboard
- Replaced the CPU (a few minutes ago)
- Removed the graphics card (it may actually be damaged)
- Replaced the CPU fan
- Added a motherboard speaker
- Replaced the screen (it turned out that the old screen actually worked)
- Pretty much gone crazy over all of this

It has a Linux and a Windows installation, but that's besides the point. It never gets near booting. When I turn it on, the screen stays black. However:

- When I turn the screen on, it turns on. The manufacturer's logo and it displays a message saying it has no HDMI input
- When I turn the computer on, it turns on. Some LEDs turn on, including annoying colored lights on the RAM DIMMs
- The speaker beeps to complain about the lack of memory if I remove the DIMMs
- I'm pretty sure that the DIMMs work
- When I turn it on, I don't hear the hard drives. That said, both OS drives are solid state
- I removed the graphics card, so the only graphics device is on the CPU (which includes a GPU) through the motherboard. Specifically, the processor is the i7 10700K
- The power button on the case works to turn on and shut down the computer, which leads me to believe that the motherboard at least partially works
- I'm pretty sure that the HDMI cable works. I'm using Raspberry Pi computers, and a ChromeBox for other things, and I've used HDMI cables for several other uses and I've never had a problem.

Currently, I'm using an old laptop, but I really want to start doing some serious work for which I'll *need* my desktop computer. Does anyone have an idea of what the issue could be?

Comment: What's the motherboard model? I had a similar problem with an x570 aorus elite.

Comment: After changing the motherboard twice, the current model is a B560M-Plus Wi-Fi. The old motherboard was wrecked by UPS. I think that the only things remaining from the old computer are the hard drives, the internal cables, and the RAM.

Comment: As long as the PSU,CPU,RAM, and motherboard are working properly you should get something on the monitor.  The only suspects left are the power supply and RAM.  Also make sure you have all the power cables connected including the 24 pin and 8 pin on the motherboard.

Comment: I'm sure they are, but I'll check again. I'll buy ONE DDR4 DIMM  just to be sure.

Comment: @cybernard One BIG thing: how likely is it that the RAM is damaged but that the motherboard doesn't beep at startup?

Comment: @eje211 Not the same model as me. I have had a problem for years wherein my PC will just not turn on first try a lot of the time.

Comment: @eje211  Did you remove the battery and do the BIOS reset procedure?  (Usually changing a jumper)  The motherboard does test the memory,

Comment: @cybernard There are no more jumpers on motherboards, as far as I can tell. I'm waiting for a DIMM with just a bit of memory to arrive so I can test it. I was also advised to take it to the Geek Squad, not to buy any of their products but just to find out which part of the computer does not work. I didn't know that was an option.